# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject always returns null

Tags: asp.net, resources, globalization, resource-management, resourcemanager

I created two files in the App_GlobalResources folder:

```
SiteResources.en-US.resx
SiteResources.sp-SP.resx
```

Both contain a value for "SiteTitleSeparator".

Here is what I am trying to do (The following line always returns null):

```
string sep = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("SiteResources", "SiteTitle");
```

Note, that the Culture property on the page is set.

Answers in both VB and C# will be welcomed.

Comment: Note, that the Culture property on the page is set.
---------------------------------------------- How did you set the culture? I have Resources.resx and Resources.fr-CA.resx, but when I read the resources, it always return the value of the default Resources.resx... Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
labUsername.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Username").ToString() + " : "; This code will not read Resources.fr-CA... Thank you

Comment: Hey philberg, I believe that for the .resx values to be used, you must set the CurrentUICulture, not the CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed the name of SiteResources.en-US.resx to SiteResources.resx and now everything works just fine.

Seems theer must be one invariant resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: there has to be one .resx without a region code which will serve as a default.